# aggregate function to return true if value exists

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, oracle12c

I've got some SQL query which returns the sum of certain fields, and there's a flag column associated with these values, either 'Y' or 'N'.

Is there an aggregate function which will return a true/false on this flag column if any  one record contains a 'Y'?

Comment: `max()`? Since Y sorts higher than N (I believe in all encodings, but not 100% sure...) Buy why PL/SQL, and do mean a true Boolean (which you can't have in plain SQL), or still a Y/N flag?

Comment: `case when max(column) = 'Y' then true else false end`

Comment: @jarlh: you need to use `'true'` - Oracle has no boolean values

Comment: I got it slightly wrong and need to return true if any row contains 'N', so i tried it with MIN() and it gives the desired result

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap conditional aggregation inside a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN column = 'Y' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm debating between this and the solution which @jarhl posted.

Comment: @atamata max / min works as well and could be faster. This one however is more generic and expresses the intention more clearly.

Comment: Agree with that, will probably be readability which decides which to use. Having said that it will extracted into a view so hopefully once it's written nobody will need to look at it again!

Answer (score 2):

```
select nvl(max(1),0) from your_table
where column = 'Y'
```

Comment: I'd prefer `COALESCE()` over `NVL()` because `COALESCE()` is part of the SQL standard and doesn't implicitly convert like `NVL()`. It will also perform short-circuit evaluation, which isn't as relevant in this specific circumstance.